# No me funciona mi setup.py

Tags: python, cmd, exe

No me funciona mi `setup.py`. Cuando lo ejecuto en símbolo del sistema dice:

`error:no commands supplied`.

Aquí dejo el código:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from distutils.core import setup 
import py2exe 

setup(name="Vivete", 
 version="1.0", 


 author_email="email del autor", 
 url="url del proyecto", 

 scripts=["Vivete.py"], 
 console=["Vivete.py"], 
 options={"py2exe": {"bundle_files": 1}}, 
 zipfile=None,
)
```

Cualquier sugerencia se las agradezco.

Comment: Por favor, indica como estás ejecutando el Script, que parámetros usas. gracias

Comment: perdón estoy ejecutándolo desde el power shell o símbolo del sistema

Comment: Y que parámetros usas? Por ejemplo `python setup.py build`?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que te falla es que no le pones el parámetro.
Prueba a ponerle "py2exe" al lado, es decir:

> setup.py py2exe